# ruby on rails wrap block of code in link_to

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I have this link_to and I can't figure out how to wrap a block of html code in it such that the div inside the link_to becomes a link. I have this code:

```
<%= link_to @favorites[0].name, {:controller => "events", :action => "search", :category => @favorites[0].name} %>
```

I have tried using "do" then <%end%> but I can't make it work.

```
     <%= link_to @favorites[0].name, {:controller => "events", :action => "search", :category => @favorites[0].name} do %>
<div> CODE HERE</div>
<%end%>
```

Any ideas on how to do this? I do not understand the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give only `path` with `link_to` when using the `block`.

```
<%= link_to({:controller =>  "events", :action => "search", :category => @favorites[0].name}) do %>
   <div> 
     <%= @favorites[0].name %> 
   </div>
<%end%>
```